# Why are true, false and nullptr prvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, rvalue

As far as I'm aware nullptr is an instance of some class, something like this:

```
const
class {
public:
    template<class T> // convertible to any type
    operator T*() const // of null non-member
    { return 0; } // pointer...
    template<class C, class T> // or any type of null
    operator T C::*() const // member pointer...
    { return 0; }
private:
    void operator&() const; // whose address can't be taken
} nullptr = {};
```

I suppose that

```
true 
false
```

are also some variables. So is the fact that thay are prvalue-s a dirty hack violating the language's type system?

If nullptr is just a keyword, then how can type be derived from it?

```
typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
```

Comment: No, `nullptr` isn't an instance of a class. Neither is `true` or `false`.

Comment: What is it, then?

Comment: Those are all three [*keywords*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). Which means the compiler recognizes them specifically as any other literal values.

Comment: `true`, `false`, and `nullptr` literals aren't really different from other literals such as `42` or `'a'`. If `42` is a prvalue, why shouldn't `true` be a prvalue?

Comment: They are values -- of either a `boolean` type, or a `nullptr_t` type.

Comment: `nullptr` is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`, which is  defined as `typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;`. See also: [std::nullptr_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) & [nullptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).

Comment: If nullptr is just a keyword, then how can type be derived from it (see updated question)?

Comment: What is it a shocker that a type can be derived from a prvalue? It's no different than `using size_t = decltype(sizeof(0))`

Comment: @StoryTeller sizeof(0) has some type, but just a brand new keyword hasn't. What is type the keyword if? decltype(if)

Comment: Yes, and the standard clearly state `nullptr` has a special type too, just like `0` has a type.

Comment: @StoryTeller Why is yet another type for nullptr (nullptr_t) introduced then? The bool isn't introduced as typedef decltype(false) bool; right?

Comment: Why? Because Bjarne baked a bool type into the language long before standardization. It's also used far more often than the type of `nullptr`, so it's convenient to have it without needing a library header. `std::size_t` and `std::nullptr_t` don't get the same honor.

Comment: So compiler just treats the keyword nullptr in a special way - that is the implementation of nullptr?

Comment: @Alexey "Why is yet another type for nullptr (nullptr_t)" - because it is useful to be able to overload functions on `nullptr_t`, to distinguish from `int` (like `0`).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Standard:

> 8.1.1 Literals [expr.prim.literal] A literal is a primary expression. Its type depends on its form (5.13). A string literal is an **lvalue**;
> all other literals are **prvalues**.
>
> <...>
>
> 5.13.6 Boolean literals [lex.bool] boolean-literal: false true
>
> The Boolean literals are the keywords false and true. Such literals are
> prvalues and have type bool.
>
> 5.13.7 Pointer literals [lex.nullptr] pointer-literal: nullptr
>
> The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. It is a prvalue of type
> std::nullptr_t. [ Note: std::nullptr_t is a distinct type that is
> neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue
> of this type is a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null
> pointer value or null member pointer value. See 7.11 and 7.12. — end
> note ]

So, as you can see, both `nullptr` and `false`/`true` obey the common rule. The only exception is a string literal (because it is essentially an array).